# Cannot call Excel AddIn in Excel macro called form Access macro

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, excel-addins

I'am creating an Access database where different clients should be stored later, currently they're stored in an Excel workbook.

I have access to the data of an SQL database (I can't change anything there) where the current Excel sheet gets client name and other informations from and I want that too in my Access database. The problem is that there is only an interface for Excel  to connect to the database. It's an Excel AddIn with a macro and I don't have access to its code.

My solution was that i run the code in Access calling a macro in an Excel sheet and that calls the Addin macro. But it's not working...

It runs the Excel macro perfecly but when that tries to run the other Excel macro it fails. Sometimes (it's different when I change the Excel macro code) I get this error in the Access VBA editor:

> Runtime error '-2147417851 (80010105)'
>   The method 'Run' for the object '_Application' is failed

**Note:** I have translated the text from german to english so it's probably not the exact error text.

And sometimes i get an error from Excel which mean the sheet which contains the AddIn macro could not be found but the addin is installed and when I debug trough the macro it works perfectly.

The AddIn is installed I have checked that with `Application.Addins(5).Name` in a for loop.

I have searched for 2 days now and I don't get further, I haven't even found someone with the same problem so far.

Here is my Access VBA code:

```
Public Sub getData(portfolioNumber As String)

Dim xlApp As Object

Dim sFile As String
Dim sClientName As String
Dim sOtherData As String

sFile = CurrentProject.Path & "\ImportSheet.xlsm"
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Workbooks.Open sFile
xlApp.Cells(5, 6).Value = portfolioNumber
xlApp.Cells(6, 6).Value = portfolioNumber

xlApp.Run "importAMSData"
sClientName = xlApp.Cells(8, 8).Value
sOtherData = xlApp.Cells(8, 9).Value
xlApp.Workbooks.Close

MsgBox (sClientName & " " & sOtherData)

Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

And here is my Excel VBA code which should call the other macro:

```
Public Sub importAMSData()

Dim iLastRow As Double
Dim iLastCol As Double
Dim dErrNo As Double

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

Dim aAddin As AddIn

Dim wbOpen As Boolean

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

ws.Activate

iLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
iLastCol = ws.Cells(7, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

If iLastRow > 7 And iLastCol > 1 Then
ws.Range(ws.Cells(8, 1), ws.Cells(iLastRow, iLastCol)).ClearContents
End If

wbOpen = False

ws.Cells(1, 2).Select
```

The AddIn should be installed by default but after it haven't worked I tried to reinstall it

```
Set aAddin = Application.AddIns.Add("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\XLSTART\SPEZM.xlam")

aAddin.Installed = True

Application.Run "SPEZM.xls!import"
```

I have also tried:

```
aAddin.Application.Run "import"
```

Often (means always if the other error not occurs) here comes an error saying that Excel haven't found Sheetname.xls but the AddIn is installed I have checked that.

I thank you for you're help and sorry for the long question.

Comment: Which line is it failing on?

Comment: Here:
Application.Run "SPEZM.xls!import"
Sometimes I get an error message: "G:\SPEZM.xls" could not be found.
The SPEZ.xls isn't even on my G: Drive. I have also tried call it by its path, but it didn't work any better.

Comment: Try fully qualifying the path to the macro. So (from memory) full workbook path in single quotes, then explanation mark, then macro name

Comment: Exclamation mark! And the whole of the above enclosed in double quotes

Comment: So like this?: Application.Run "'C: \Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\XLSTART\SPEZM.xls'!import"

Comment: The result was the error explained in the main question...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Are there any macro security settings issues perhaps?

Comment: Because I'm working in a bank thats probably the reason. However it works in debug mode. Is it perhaps the case that the macro security doesn't block macros called by the user but macros called by other macros..?

Comment: Possibly.  I just got an example working on my machine using: 
    xl.Run "'c:\temp\SPEZM.xls'!Import"

Comment: I will try it otherwise now, thank  you for your support.

Comment: I tried open it now with a separate .bat file and with a .vbs file but it haven't worked either. The .bat file crashs Excel and with the .vbs I get the same error as before (G:\SPEZM.xls not found). I dont have any others ideas now...